# pyautogui could not locate image exception even though it exists

Tags: python, error-handling, pyautogui

I am Using Pyautogui Library for image tracing for a long time.
I don't know why but I just got a new laptop and it's not working for me at all.
It throws the Image not found Error Even if image exists.
I can guarantee that image path is also absolute Correct.
Even I Tried a
simple program Like I've Given Below But It Still Shows Me Error.

Is There Anyone Who Can Help ?
Really Appreciate It.
Thank You!

```py
from pyautogui import *

a = locateOnScreen("E:/Mark 7/Test.png")

print(a)

if not (a == None):

    print("Got Image")

if(a==None):

    print("Oops!")
```

When I Tried This, I got This Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DELL INC\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 172, in wrapper
    return wrappedFunction(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\DELL INC\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 210, in locateOnScreen
    return pyscreeze.locateOnScreen(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\DELL INC\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 405, in locateOnScreen
    retVal = locate(image, screenshotIm, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\DELL INC\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 383, in locate
    points = tuple(locateAll(needleImage, haystackImage, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\DELL INC\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 371, in _locateAll_pillow
    raise ImageNotFoundException('Could not locate the image.')
pyscreeze.ImageNotFoundException: Could not locate the image.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Mark 7\Test.py", line 3, in <module>
    a = locateOnScreen("E:\\Mark 7\\Test.png")
  File "C:\Users\DELL INC\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 174, in wrapper
    raise ImageNotFoundException  # Raise PyAutoGUI's ImageNotFoundException.
pyautogui.ImageNotFoundException
```

Comment: use `try` and `except` in your code

Comment: maybe check what you have in `Test.png`. You can also get screenshot and compare it with `Test.png` to see if they have the same object. Maybe they have much different size and this makes problem.

Comment: BTW: If it had problem to find file on disk then it would show `raise IOError("Failed to read %s because file is missing, "
`

Comment: Maybe start with simple `print( os.path.exists("E:/Mark 7/Test.png") )` to check if this file really exists for Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the confidence parameter. Like this.
pyautogui.locateOnScreen("E:/Mark 7/Test.png", confidence=0.7)

ImageNotFoundException doesn't actually mean there is no "E:/Mark 7/Test.png" file.

I think, ImageNotFoundException means that a pattern matching the image cannot be found on the screen.

You can properly handle exceptions using the try: except: statement.